# Sending and receiving many intents per second

Tags: android, android-intent

Is there any downside to sending and receiving lets say 5-10 intents per second?
I have one thread which receives a few packages per second and has to notify an activity for each of them. I want the two components to be independent i.e. on class should not hold a reference to an object from the other.
So I intend to to send broadcast intents for each package and receive them in the activity class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it shouldn't be a problem as long as you make sure your program is *never* blocked. Make sure you run everything in paralell threads.

Don't use AsyncTask, Android has a 128 threadpool limit on those as far as I know. That would fill up within a few seconds.